# Callout is calling a diferent endpoint

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Hi i'm new in wso2 and I have 2 api's, I want to call the second one using the first, but the url that the callout mediator is using is diferente from the one I set up, resulting in error  HTTPSender Unable to sendViaGet to url[http://192.168.20.1:8280/loginAPI/login/Nurse]

The code is below

Any help will be welcome

```
<api context="/Staff" name="StaffAPI" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<resource methods="GET" url-mapping="/Nurse">
    <inSequence>
        <log level="full"/>
        <callout description="" initAxis2ClientOptions="false" serviceURL="http://192.168.20.1:8280/loginAPI/login">
            <source type="envelope"/>
            <target key="response"/>
        </callout>
        <log level="custom">
            <property expression="get-property('response')" name="response"/>
        </log>
        <send>
            <endpoint key="NurseEP"/>
        </send>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
        <send/>
    </outSequence>
    <faultSequence/>
</resource>
```

```
<api context="/loginAPI" name="LoginAPI" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<resource methods="GET" uri-template="/login">
    <inSequence>
        <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{&#xd;
                "userName": "xxx",&#xd;
                "password": "xxx",&#xd;
                "rememberMe": true,&#xd;
                "fireBaseToken": "string"&#xd;
            }</format>
            <args/>
        </payloadFactory>
        <cache collector="false" hashGenerator="org.wso2.carbon.mediator.cache.digest.DOMHASHGenerator" id="Token" maxMessageSize="2000" scope="per-host" timeout="5000">
            <onCacheHit/>
            <implementation maxSize="1000" type="memory"/>
        </cache>
        <send>
            <endpoint key="LoginEP"/>
        </send>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
        <cache collector="true" scope="per-host"/>
        <send/>
    </outSequence>
    <faultSequence/>
</resource>
```

The http://192.168.20.1:8280/loginAPI/login endpoint when called on postman is valid

Comment: Can you add "NurseEP" configs and "loginAPI" login resource configs as well?

Comment: Did you follow the steps described in https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Callout+Mediator?

Comment: Yes, I tried more than once already, just in case I skipe a step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams that your serviceURL is suffixed by your api url-mapping, try to add that before callout (it has to be used in case of send mediator, not sure for callout but it looks like the same behavior) :

```
<property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
```

Comment: Now i'm getting 

HTTPSender Unable to sendViaGet to url[http://192.168.20.1:8280/loginAPI/login]

and this endpoint is working, I tested just now